# Elasticsearch API: difference between SearchQuery and SearchResponse?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my Spring-Data-Elasticsearch application, I am trying to use SearchQuery to search through Elasticsearch, according to some given QueryBuilder and FilterBuilder.

However, [Elasticsearch docs talk about SearchResponse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html), which to me, seems to do the same work as SearchQuery.

I don't understand the difference between SearchQuery and SearchResponse.
Can someone please point out the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the query object to an elasticsearch client and execute the query you get a response back.
The response type is dependent on the query type.

```
executed SearchQuery object -> SearchResponse object
executed IndexQuery object -> IndexResponse object
```

and so on...

In the code snippet of your link the SearchQuery object is build with the prepareSearch method. Afterwards it gets executed by the client.

```
SearchResponse response = 
  // Query creation part
  client.prepareSearch("index1", "index2")
        .setTypes("type1", "type2")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("multi", "test"))             
        .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("age").from(12).to(18))   
        .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)

        //query execution part
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

The search query is the query you send to Elastic, the search response is Elasticsearch's response to that query.

For example, this could be your query:

```
POST /your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "available": {
        "value": true
      }
    }
  }
```

And a possible query response from ES:

```
{
   "took": 99,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 58188,
      "max_score": 0.99998283,
      "hits": [
         ...
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!